# Como verificar se arquivo existe (assíncrono)

Tags: node.js, assincronismo, fs

Em Node.JS, eu utilizo este método do `fs` para verificar se um arquivo existe:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// [...]

if (fs.existsSync(path)) { /** Do stuff. */ }
```

A pergunta é: como posso fazer a mesma coisa, mas de forma **assíncrona**?
*Nota: utilizo o Node 8.10.0.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar o método [`fs.access`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback).

```
fs.access(path, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
  console.log(err ? 'não existe' : 'existe');
});
```

Mas atente-se à documentação:

> *Using `fs.access()` to check for the accessibility of a file before calling `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible.*

Ou seja, se for verificar a existência do arquivo para, posteriormente, manipulá-lo, esta forma não é recomendada, pois cria condições de corrida e outras partes da aplicação podem alterar o estado do arquivo entre as chamadas.

O recomendado é você tratar a exceção quando alterar o arquivo, caso o mesmo não exista.

```
fs.open(path, 'r', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      console.error('Arquivo não existe');
      return;
    }

    throw err;
  }

  funcao_que_le_arquivo(fd);
});
```

<sup>Exemplo adaptado da própria documentação</sup>

Comment: Então como seria uma boa prática para fazê-lo (seguindo a nota da documentação)? Poderia dar um exemplo na resposta acima?

Comment: @Iffg seria modificar o arquivo diretamente, sem verificar e tratar a exceção disparada caso o arquivo não existe. Tem vários exemplos na documentação citada.